# Weird ClassCastException when deserializing in onRestoreInstanceState

Tags: android

In `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
// departures is instance of Departures which extends ArrayList
bundle.putSerializable("departures", departures);
```

In `onRestoreInstanceState`:

```
departures = (Departures) state.getSerializable("departures");
```

When I rotate the screen, the Activity is restarted and it's state is restored. It works ok. In case I leave the Activity, after some time Android removes it from memory and saves its state. When I return to it, it crashes in `onRestoreInstanceState`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to cz.fhejl.pubtran.Departures
```

The `getSerializable` now returned `ArrayList`, not `Departures`.

Edit: here's how Departures.java looks: http://pastebin.com/qc3QfrK7

Comment: Here: http://pastebin.com/qc3QfrK7

Comment: I added a string field to your class to hold some data, and was able to save and restore the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you see is caused by the way Android flattens the objects. Internally it will call [`Parcel#writeValue(Object)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/os/Parcel.java#Parcel.writeValue%28java.lang.Object%29) which has a long chain of if / else and the `if (o instanceof List)` comes before `instanceof Serializable`. Since `Departures` is a `List` it will put it as a list instead and when unparcelling the data it does not know that it was a special kind of list.

You need to use something that does not extend a `List` to get around that problem.

Answer (score 4):

I know I am a bit late on this one but I came across a similar problem with an array of serializables.

I made it work by wrapping the array within a private class of my own.

```
private class ArrayHolder implements Serializable{
  public Serializable[] _myArray;
  public ArrayHolder(Serializable myArray){
    _myArray = myArray;
  }
}
```

Then to save all I did was

```
bundle.putSerializable("name",new ArrayHolder(arrayToBeSaved));
```

When deserializing:

```
ArrayHolder arrayHolder = (ArrayHolder) bundle.getSerializable("name");
arrayRecovered = arrayHolder._myArray;
```

I have no idea WHY it works but it does.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the problem I had. It would serialize my arrays to simple Object[] instead of the correct custom class based array.